# How to create sequence in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can we create sequence in SQL Server? I am creating like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE counter
AS INT
MINVALUE 1
NO MAXVALUE
START WITH 1;
```

but getting below error

> Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Unknown object type 'SEQUENCE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version MS SQL Server do you use ?
As I know SEQUNCE's have been added only in 2012 version.

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;

    SELECT next value for CountBy1
```

In SQL Server 2012 above is the syntax to create and consume created sequence.

Comment: Sequences have been added only in 2012 version

Comment: By mistake i wrote 2008 version. i have updated the given answer.